# Categories without isomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, functors

A groupoid is a category in which every morphism is an isomorphism. I'm looking at a dual case: categories in which none morphism (except identites) is an isomorphism.

- These kind of categories are well-studied?
- There are implications of the assumption in terms of existence of limits/colimits?
- There is some characterization of them?

For instance, notice that if $\mathbf{D}$ is without isomorphisms, then there is no functor $F:\mathbf{C}\rightarrow \mathbf{D}$ where $\mathbf{C}$ is a category which has at least one isomorphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ with $F(Y) \neq F(X)$. This means that *categories without isomorphisms are typically not codomain of functors*.

On the other hand, one can always enlarge a category by adding isomorphisms (for instance, take a set of weak equivalences and consider some localization at them). This shows that *categories without isomorphisms can be domain of functors*.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Partial order categories would be an example.

Comment: Yep! Thank you.

Comment: If $\mathbb{D}$ is a category without isomorphisms, you actually can have functors from categories with nontrivial isomorphisms to $\mathbb{D}$, although these basically quotient out at isomorphism. For example if $\mathbb{C} = \mathbf{Set}$ and if $1$ is the terminal category, then for any object $X$ of $\mathbb{D}$, we have a functor $\underline{X}:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{D}$ given by projecting onto $1$ and then mapping $1$ to the object $X$ and the identity morphism on $X$.

Comment: Thank you for the remark.

Comment: I think that if $F:\mathbf{C}\rightarrow \mathbf{D}$ is a functor and $D$ is without isomorphisms, if there is some $f:X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathbf{C}$ which is an isomorphism, then $Y=X$, i.e, it is an automophism.

Comment: You must have $F(Y) = F(X)$, but not necessarily $Y = X$: see Geoff's example.

Comment: By replacing a category by its [skeleton](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton), you can see that you are looking at categories such that every object has a trivial automorphism group. So for instance, for any object $X$, if $X^2$ exists it must be $X$ with the two identities as projections...

Comment: What does the quotient of the category of sets by making every isomorphism the identity looks like?

Comment: @Rob Arthan. You are right. Thank you.

Comment: @Idéophage Thank you for this remark on moving to the skeleton.

Comment: This is sometimes called a [gaunt category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gaunt+category).

Comment: Thank you! This will help me a lot.